# Wrong ripple in material3 NavigationBar in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation-bar, android-jetpack-compose-material3

When I use Material3 `NavigationBar` in Jetpack Compose I get wrong rectangular ripple effect like this:

[image]

Material3 library version: `1.0.0-alpha06`
Code:

```kotlin
NavigationBar(modifier = Modifier.navigationBarsPadding()) {
                NavigationBarItem(
                    selected = ...,
                    onClick = {
                        navController.navigate(ScreenComponents(context).mainScreen) {
                            launchSingleTop = true
                        }
                    },
                    icon = {
                        ...
                    },
                    alwaysShowLabel = false,
                    label = {
                        Text(text = ..., color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface)
                    }
                )
                // ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a bug. It follows the [material guidelines](https://m3.material.io/components/navigation-bar/specs#465dd07e-5315-4c9f-8d37-aba92887a693).

[image]

Comment: Seems like this isn't the case anymore and they've updated the guidelines to have the ripple on the 'pill' only, so I guess this is still an open issue. [Guidelines](https://m3.material.io/components/navigation-bar/specs#465dd07e-5315-4c9f-8d37-aba92887a693).

Answer (score 3):

They seem to have changed the guideline images since the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72092733/10082297) from @Gabriele Mariotti and now the ripple only appears on the 'pill'.

[image: Guidelines]

There is an easy way to disable the ripple entirely, but not to isolate it to the pill. Hopefully they update this before the M3 composables come out of alpha.

```kotlin
private object NoRippleTheme : RippleTheme {
    @Composable
    override fun defaultColor() = Color.Transparent

    @Composable
    override fun rippleAlpha() = RippleAlpha(0F, 0F, 0F, 0F)
}
```

```kotlin
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalRippleTheme provides NoRippleTheme) {
        NavigationBar {
            ...
```

Answer (score 2):

In **NavigationBarItem** I use this modifier to change the shape of the ripple

```
modifier = Modifier
    .padding(4.dp)
    .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background, RoundedCornerShape(24.dp))
    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(24.dp))
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to remove a ripple effect on the pill by specifying a custom interaction source:

```
private object NoRippleInteractionSource : MutableInteractionSource {

    override val interactions: Flow<Interaction> = emptyFlow()

    override suspend fun emit(interaction: Interaction) {}

    override fun tryEmit(interaction: Interaction) = true
}
```

and passing this interaction source as an argument:

```
NavigationBarItem(
    interactionSource = NoRippleInteractionSource,
    selected = isSelected,
    onClick = onClick,
    ...
)
```